# Showing that a norm in the space of summable series is well defined

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Consider the sequence space
> $$S_C=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:x_n\in\mathbb{F}, \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ is convergent}\right\}$$
> of summable sequences. This is a linear space.

Show that $\lVert(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\rVert =\sup_n | \sum_{k=1}^n x_k |$ is a norm on $S_C$.

I've been able to prove every requirement except that I haven't been able to show that if $\lVert(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\rVert=0$, then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=0$.

Sorry for the short question, but I can't seem to find information about this space. Also I would be thankful for any information regarding this space $S_C$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\mathbb{F}, \vert \cdot \vert)$ be the initial normed vector space. Clearly the norm you define on $S_C$ is absolutely homogenous, non-negative and it satisfies the triangle inequality by the properties of the initial norm and the supremum as you have pointed out. Moreover, the norm of the zero-vector is clearly equal to zero. Thus let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in S_C$ be such that $\Vert (x_n) \Vert = 0,$ so $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \vert \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} x_k \vert = 0.$ This means that all of these absolute values are equal to zero, so by the properties of $\vert \cdot \vert,$ we have that $S_n := \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} x_k = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ In particular, $x_n = S_{n + 1} - S_n = 0,$ so $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the zero-vector. I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this by induction. You know that

$$ |x_1| = \bigg|\sum_{k=1}^1 x_k\bigg| \le \|(x_n)\| = 0, $$

so $x_1 = 0$. You can show that $x_2 = 0$ using the fact that $x_1 = 0$ and a very modest modification of the above logic. Do induction to show every term is $0$. Do you see how to proceed?